# htaccess detect missing language and rewrite url

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Spent hours and read many similar questions here, but still dont get it...

**URL looks like this**
http://www.example.com/en/member/set_dashboard

**I got the following .htaccess entries**

```
Action php /cgi-php54/php
AddHandler php54 .php

AddType application/x-javascript .js

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)$ index.php?lang=$1
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+).htm$ index.php?lang=$1
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+).htm$ index.php?lang=$1&href=$2
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+).htm$ index.php?lang=$1&href=$2&topic=$3

RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)$ index.php?lang=$1&href=$2&topic=$3
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/.]+)/([^/\.]+)$ index.php?lang=$1&href=$2&topic=$3&sub=$4
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)$ index.php?lang=$1&href=$2&topic=$3&sub=$4&attr=$5
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)$ index.php?lang=$1&href=$2&topic=$3&sub=$4&attr=$5&out=$6
```

**How can I rewrite the URL when the language is missing?** Example:
http://www.example.com/member/set_dashboard should turn into 
http: //www.example.com/**en**/member/set_dashboard

Default language could be 'en', but if somehow possible, i'd prefer to use visitors browser language!

Your help is very much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Then I think the Mod_GeoIP  would be great to use.

http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/mod_geoip2/

Comment: thanks for that Timm, will definitively have a look at that. But i'm still struggling with the URL rewrite :/